# what is IOS 6 equivalent to “maximumUpdateValueLength” get same value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

According to IOS Developer Library documentation `maximumUpdateValueLength` provide maximum amount of data, in bytes, that the central can receive in a single notification or indication. Is there similar way to get the same thing done by IOS 6 because `maximumUpdateValueLength` is only for IOS 7 ?

Documentation for `maximumUpdateValueLength`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentral_Class/Reference/CBCentral.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBCentral/maximumUpdateValueLength

Comment: Since in the iOS 6.1 to iOS 7.0 API Differences, `maximumUpdateValueLength` is added, but nothing like modified, and nothing seems to do the same in iOS6, I'd say you can't.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for reply. Do you know any alternative method to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out the maximum packet size is to respond with long data to a read request. For details on how you should implement it, search other SO questions or check out the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW6). The maximum data length for a single read or write is 512 bytes. You shouldn't try with longer data. You will be able to determine the maximum length by observing the increments of the `offset` parameter. E.g. if you see the values: 0, 20, 40 in subsequent callbacks, then you can deduct that the max length is 20 bytes.

If you want to determine the value at runtime and use it programmatically in your code, then you'll have to create your own solution based on this method.

As a hint. With the iPhone4S you'll see 20 bytes and the iPhone5+ will give something around 120 bytes. But best is to not build on this value and try to design your code to be as general as possible.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  According to sample code from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927 it' s a fix value with 20 bytes. So I think it' s better to send 20 bytes first and increase or decrease base on the getting or not getting from centre side.

Comment: Yes, I described the same in the last paragraph. But note that on the iPh5 and later the size may be different. Though there doesn't seem to be any compelling reason to use it as experience shows that transfer speed can actually decrease by doing so.

Comment: Btw, if you think I helped you, please acceept the answer with the tick mark under the vote number. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: The reason for not making that your answer accepted is because I ask this question to get something easy way to do it in IOS 6 like in IOS 7. What you have tell also can do in IOS 7 too. So it's not specific to IOS devices which have IOS versions before IOS 7. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: There is no library that does this for you. A friend of mine works on something that may help but that is months away from being published. You need to implement what I described. It is general for any iOS version, not just iOS7. But as iOS7 gives you this info practically for free, I wouldn't bother using the same method there. I feel it a little unfair that you expect a complete solution for 10  or so reps.

Comment: Ok, Ok I accepted it :D, But I thought same thing before I ask this question.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Usually questions on SO provide a good feedback that your train of thoughts is going in the right direction. Core Bluetooth is lacking a lot of tools, there are no, or very cumbersome utility libraries, so it's very likely that only the more labor intensive solution exists for an issue. Specifically, for your question it is advised not to build on the max transfer size.